# How can I access my XAMPP site using my IP instead of localhost?

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I have port forwarded and it is possible to access my site from other other networks. I am also able to access it - but only if I use "localhost" as the URL. This causes some problems, which I won't go into detail on since I don't think they're relevant. Anyways, friends are able to access the site by typing in my IP address. When I do so, it fails to load.

Comment: You need to provide some basic details, like error messages for example

Comment: The only error message I'm getting is "Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at pxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.]" Nothing in the server logs or anything. I'm not sure what other information I can provide that would be helpful - I'm running Windows 10 if that makes a difference.

Comment: There could be tons of things. This is something you'd be better off posting on server fault: http://serverfault.com/